# Running Windows 7 on a KVM exposed to Internet for RDP connections

Tags: windows, security, rdp

I have Windows 7 Professional running on a KVM machine strictly for use as a remote support gateway, and it's currently exposed to the internet.  I realize this is not exactly the best method for a support gateway, but this is the best we could come up with in lieu of driving to the data center in the middle of the night.

The KVM machine we have is old and will not run a newer and more secure operating system.  It's not used very much, but it needs to be available 24x7.

This is what we have done already to secure this machine:

- Running RDP on a non-standard port.
- FailBan and firewall is running
  on our primary servers.
- Windows Firewall is enabled on the Windows 7 support computer.
- DDOS is enabled by the Data Center.

I am looking for advice on how best to protect the exposed computer or tips on what else we should be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can only run the software on the Windows 7 machine, your options are limited.

- If you have a Remote Desktop Services environment with RDGW setup already, require people to log into a RDSH and then remote desktop into the Windows 7 machine.
- Setup a VPN so that users can connect to the desktop using a private IP address, and the traffic will be encrypted

Comment: Why would you assume RDP is not meant to be used "raw across the internet"? A Windows server remote desktop environment is a very common way for businesses to provide their clients with a consistent desktop environment. Of course a lot depends on the way your set it up, but you certainly can provide encrypted rdp connections.

Comment: I am going to set up a VPN. That seems to be the only option.

Comment: @EarthMind I used raw to mean unencrypted

Comment: @NonSecwitter I understood that, but you're wrong. RDP connections are using native RDP encryption by standard, but you can also set it up to use TLS encryption for improved security.

Comment: ah. my mistake. I'll update